# devel WAMP stack with mail server and open SSL

Tags: php, development-environment, openssl, wamp

I'm developing an application that requires testing email.

I'm currently using wampserver, but it doesn't come with a mail server and setting one up has been a pain.

Also if I use an external mail server like yahoo, I run into issues because wamp doesn't come with SSL which yahoo's mail server requires.

So I'm trying to save myself from all this headache. I'm looking for a new development environment that comes "out of the box" with a mailserver and open SSL. Clearly that's not wampserver2. What does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in your other question, [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) does.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any reasonably popular Linux distro has these built-in.

Comment: wampserver2 is not a Linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

As i said in another question - settle fake GMail account and use PHPMailer.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleagmail